# Is it possible to install Python on Mac OSX without sudo permissions?

Tags: mac, permissions, python

I know this has been answered for people using Linux but I for the life of me cannot get Python 3.6.4 to work on a Mac I do not have sudo rights on.

I have run the commands

```
curl -OL http://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.6.4/Python-3.6.4.tgz  
tar xzvf Python-3.6.4.tgz  
cd Python-3.6.4
make
./configure --prefix=/Users/$(myusername)/
make install
```

It still gives me a permission denied error when creating the bin and lib folders after I run the make install command. Could anyone give me a different path to install to that will not be blocked?

Answer (score 2):

So apparently the command is

```
./configure --prefix=/Users/(username)/path/to/wherever --enable-shared
```

I just made a new folder and stuck Python in there. After that I just had to change the PATH variable and it worked fine from the terminal as well.

Comment: what is `/path/to/wherever`?

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me, i am able to bring up a python shell , create a virtualenv and pip install

```
cd ~/Downloads
curl -L -O https://www.python.org/ftp/python/3.10.4/python-3.10.4-macos11.pkg

mkdir -p /Users/volden/opt/Python.framework
cd /Users/volden/opt/Python.framework
xar -xf ~/Downloads/python-3.10.4-macos11.pkg
for i in `find . | grep Payload`; do mv $i $i.gz; gunzip $i.gz; done
for i in `find . | grep Payload`; do cpio -iv < $i ; done

export DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH=/Users/volden/opt:$DYLD_FRAMEWORK_PATH
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/Users/volden/opt/Python.framework/Versions/3.10/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Without the second export there will be SSL errors , “import ssl” will spew errors unable to load libssl dylib